# Adding account through API, address field causing error

Tags: rest-api, account, address, postman

Currently I am trying to create a new account using Postman before I implement the API code programically and I am running into an error. First here is the error.

```
[
{
    "message": "Unable to create/update fields: BillingAddress. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE",
    "fields": [
        "BillingAddress"
    ]
}
]
```

BillingAddress is an Address Data Type.
Here is the JSON I am passing.

```
{
"RecordTypeId": "0124W000001LQCqQAO",
"Customer_ID__c": "999999",
"Name": "Pat James",
"PersonEmail": "anyemail@gmail.com",
"Phone": "469-989-4567",
"Sign_Up_date__c": "2021-01-19",
"BillingAddress": {
 "street": "3242 Main Street",
 "city": "Dallas",
 "state": "Texas",
 "postalCode": "75235",
 "country": "USA"
 }
}
```

I have gone through the Setup and made sure this field is accessible by the System Admin user I am using right now. Just totally confused as to why this isn't working.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Comment: Try using BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, and BillingCountry like you did for the other fieds in your json

Comment: I cannot change the names of the address object, those are required to get to this point and built into Salesforce. For example, if I change street to BillingStreet I will get a JSON Parser error due to the invalid field name.

Comment: I mean, BillingAdress type is a compound field with all the fields I gave you. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm

Comment: One step closer thank you. I removed the BillingAddress and added the fields as you suggested. Now I receive a different error. Business Account may not use Person Account field PersonEmail. Time to start troubleshooting this one.

Comment: *PersonEmail* field is specific for Account using Record-Type **PersonAccount**. The Record-Type Id you pass is a **Business** Record-Type. Change the record type you pass for business RT or use *Email* field insted of *PersonEmail*

Comment: Thank you Badbaxx, going to work on trying to find the correct Record-Type ID since Email does not seem to be recognized as a field with the current setup I am working with.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake, there is no standard field **Email** on Account but you can have **PersonEmail** on PersonAccount

Comment: I am brand new to Salesforce itself, someone else setup the existing structure, anyway you could point me in the right direction on how to change record type. Have been searching through salesforce all morning with no luck. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: First check RecordType avalable for Account object on your Org. You have to know that RecordType Id is different in each salesforce Org. You can request RecordType Id with SOQL

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, but when I removed it from the composite field context in my JSOM I was successful, when making REST API calls and needing to use this field DO NOT do it this way:

```
       `"BillingAddress": {
         "street": "StreetTest",
         "city": "CityTest",
         "state": "NC",
         "postalCode": "12460-000",
         "country": "USA"
     },`
```

Now if you separate the fields like this below it will work:

```
"BillingCity":"CityTest",
"BillingStreet: "StreetTest",
 ...
```

Comment: More generally, *compound fields (Address and Geolocation) are always read only*. The approach you describe here is how you'll handle all compound fields.